# How to use servlet.shepherd for downloading public documents with Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, content, document

I'm presently using this for our production, which is working

ServletShepherdBaseUrl = @"http://companyname.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/";

What would be the equivalent for me to get it working with a developer pro sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer that worked for me:

http://mysandbox-mycompany.myinstance.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/

[Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_overview.htm)